# Find key and update it's value and the next key value [Javascript Object]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this object:

```
{
  foo:'Value foo',
  bar:'Value bar',
  baz:'Value baz',
  bor:'Value bor',
}
```

I want to check if key has changed i need to update the rest value of key changes,

so if i change `bar` values into `another value` i want to set `baz` and `bor` value = `null`, something like this:

```
{
  foo:'Value foo',
  bar:'another value',
  baz:null,
  bor:null,
}
```

i've tried with this code, but it's change all value that's not the same:

```
let obj2 = {
    foo:'Value foo',
    bar:'Value bar',
    baz:'Value baz',
    bor:'Value bor',
  }
let tempValue = obj
for (var k in tempValue){
  if(k == 'bar'){
    tempValue[k] = 'another value'
  } else {
    tempValue[k] = null
  }
}
console.log('tempValue', tempValue)
  -> {foo: null, bar: "another value", baz: null, bor: null}

//expected output
{foo: 'Value foo', bar: "another value", baz: null, bor: null}
```

Comment: So basically you will have two object one is old and one is present, so if in present any of the value changed starting from the next property everything should be null, Is this whats your expected output

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS yes, if i change those requirement into index, `while(currentValueIndexChange > totalIndex){update value to null}`

Comment: basically i have one doubt is, the order of the object will be same, I have read somewhere it will be different across browsers. So here what i was thinking something like we need to compare each property since the key is same, now at a point we will be finding a diff of value, so keeping that key as the start from there all the next properties will be null . This is what i am thinking. Will post in sometime

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS, _I have read somewhere it will be different across browsers_ || actually i'm not web dev , so i add extra tag to react and react-native because i'm a react-native dev

Comment: Sure, will try :). SO is sharing and helping isn't. Will figure out

Comment: Did the while worked for you

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS glad to hear that :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225313/discussion-between-dileep-thomas-and-flix).

Comment: @ flix, kindly check the answer so if it helped kindly vote and accept so it will be helpful for future references

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

```js
const example = {
  foo: "Value foo",
  bar: "Value bar",
  baz: "Value baz",
  bor: "Value bor",
};

const theFunctionYouNeed = (obj, key, value) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj);
  const idx = keys.indexOf(key);
  if (idx == -1) return;
  obj[keys[idx]] = value;
  for (let i = idx + 1; i < keys.length; i++) {
    obj[keys[i]] = null;
  }
};

theFunctionYouNeed(example, "bar", "another value");

console.log(example); // { foo: 'Value foo', bar: 'another value', baz: null, bor: null }
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the below snippet. I hope this will give you a better understanding

```js
let old = {
  foo: "Value foo",
  bar: "Value bar",
  baz: "Value baz",
  bor: "Value bor",
};

let present = {
  foo: "Value foo",
  bar: "another value",
  baz: "Value baz",
  bor: "Value bor",
};

// find the key from where we need to start replacing

let startingKey = Object.keys(present).find((key) => old[key] !== present[key]);
let indexOfStartingKey = Object.keys(present).indexOf(startingKey);

let data = Object.keys(present).reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (Object.keys(present).indexOf(curr) > indexOfStartingKey) {
    acc[curr] = null;
  } else {
    acc[curr] = present[curr];
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(data)
```